# What are my chances of getting into an REU program?

Tags: research-undergraduate

I am currently trying to apply to 7 different environmental REU programs and was wondering what my chances of getting into one would be.

I am a current senior pursuing a B.S. in Environmental Science with minors in French and Environmental Toxicology and will be continuing my 5th year next year (I switched majors in Sophomore year). I go to North Carolina State University, a R1 university, my GPA is 3.92, and I am a female, Asian-American first-generation college student who comes from a low-income middle class family (close to my state's qualifications for the "poverty" line). I have experience as a research assistant who assisted with research on aquatic stressors on aquatic macroinvertebrates, and I won a research grant from my university to conduct environmental engineering research last year.

I am seeking to participate in an REU because I would like to pursue a PhD and would like to learn as much as I can through research experiences in preparation for grad school. Right now, I would like to experience research outside of my home institution since I would like to explore graduate school options and other kinds of environmental/aquatic research, and the living expenses being covered would be incredibly helpful for me since I nor my family would have no way of paying for my living expenses.

Unfortunately (or fortunately?), being at a R1 university and having had other previous research experiences, I am unsure as to how likely it would be for me to get accepted into an REU program. I understand that most of these programs seek underrepresented minorities from liberal arts or community colleges with little research experience, therefore I am seeking a realistic analysis on whether or not I can get accepted into an REU program. I was told by others that I should exclude the fact that I got a research grant, but I am unsure as to how to feel about fabricating the truth to make it seem as if I have had little research experience. I am at a loss for what to do, but I have to complete my personal statements by next Friday, and I am rather stressed about my odds of acceptance.

Any advice would be greatly greatly appreciated. Just as a heads up: there are unfortunately not many other REUs with research/themes specific to the field I am going into (Non-marine Aquatic chemistry/ecology), so that is why I am only applying to 7 programs. Most other environmental REU programs are focused on forestry, climate change, or marine & coastal sciences as far as I can tell.

Comment: You have to apply, we don't have their criteria that they will use to evaluate candidates.

Comment: _I am unsure as to how to feel about fabricating the truth_ — Good! **Do. Not. Lie.**

Answer (score 1):

"I am unsure as to how to feel about fabricating the truth to make it seem as if I have had little research experience."

Experience is good.  Just clearly explain how your work at the REU will be different from what you can do at your home institution.

Do include your demographic information.

Carefully check the rules to see if you are still eligible after four years of undergraduate study.  Carefully explain why you are doing a fifth year of undergraduate study.

It is normal to feel stressed, but there is no need to worry.  Not much is at stake, and you have a good chance of success.  Seven applications is plenty.